# what javascript object am I looking for? click a button-it stays bold till the next one is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A very basic thing, I know.  I have a collapsing div help box thing that is triggered when clicking links.  Click the link, the help topic opens in the div.

I want the text in the link to stay bold until I click another link.  What function am i looking for?  I'm using jquery.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all your help links have a class of "help", define a class:

```
a.last { font-weight: bold; }
```

and then:

```
$("a.help").click(function() {
  $("a.last").removeClass("last");
  $(this).addClass("last");
});
```