# How do I extend this javascript to change the class of two elements in one onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Cletus helped my with this really sweet code yesterday:
[what javascript object am I looking for? click a button-it stays bold till the next one is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063122/what-javascript-object-am-i-looking-for-click-a-button-it-stays-bold-till-the-n)

This takes the class of my li and changes the class. It works great!  I'm wanting to extend this so it will also change the class within the a in the li.  How do I do that?

Example:

```
<ul>
 <li class="old_class"><a class="old_class" ...>
 <li class="old_class"><a class="old_class" ...>
 <li class="old_class"><a class="old_class" ...>
</ul>

So when I click the first link it would become:

<ul>
 <li class="new_class"><a class="new_class" ...>
 <li class="old_class"><a class="old_class" ...>
 <li class="old_class"><a class="old_class" ...>
</ul>
```

As the code is now, the li class changes, but not the a.

The code I'm using:

```
$(".old_class").click(function() {
  $(".new_class").removeClass("new_class");
  $(this).addClass("new");
});
```

Thank you!  I'm using Jquery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define you `ul`  with a `class`, say `<ul class="nav">...`

Then:

```
var navItems = $('.nav > li');
navItems.click (function () {
    navItems.children ('a').andSelf ()
        .removeClass ('new_class').addCass ('old_class');
    $(this).children ('a').andSelf ()
        .removeClass ('old_class').addClass ('new_class');
});
```

That said, you don't need any class in the children `a` - you could refer to them in CSS as simply `.new_class a`

Comment: I just realized that myself about being able to just do the .new_class a thing.  So much to learn :-D  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(".old_class").click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("old_class");
  $(this).children("a").removeClass("old_class");
  $(this).addClass("new_class");
  $(this).children("a").addClass("new_class");
});
```

Comment: Hi-That worked to change both classes, but it's not toggling the old ones back...This is on a nav-bar type thing where the li and a are changing until a different li and a are clicked and then go back to their old state...